# Why are some $_POST variables passing to refreshed page and others are not?

Tags: php, post

***I fixed this by adding all values to an array in a separate loop.  Thanks for the help.***

The `$_POST['val1']` variable is passing to the refreshed page, but the `$_POST['val2']` is not.  The code for each is the same, and they are both within the same form.  Any ideas are welcome.  At this point, I think I really just need a fresh set of eyes on this.

I am just including snippets of the code so it is easier to look at.  Everything else in the program is running correctly, and I am not getting any specific errors... just that the value for `$_POST['val2']` is not printing.

Here is the code where the `$_POST` variables are defined:

```
// foreach ($line as $col_value) ...
if ($counter == 1):
    echo "\t\t<input type='hidden' name='val1'   value='$col_value' />";
elseif ($counter == 2):
    echo "\t\t<input type='hidden' name='val2' value='$col_value' />";
endif;
```

Here is the code where they are used:

```
for($i=1; $i<6; $i++) {
    echo "\t<tr>\n";
    echo "\t\t<td>";

    if($i == 1){
        echo "id";
        echo "</td>\n";
        echo "\t\t<td>" . $_POST['val1'] . "</td>\n";

    } elseif($i == 2){
        echo "name";
        echo "</td>\n";
        echo "\t\t<td>" . $_POST['val2'] . "</td>\n";
```

Comment: you have a if\elseif block. only one will ever be posted. either val1 or val2 NEVER both

Comment: Quick note - your code would be much more readable and easier to maintain, if you use single quotes `''` and concatenate the expressions, for example: `echo "\t\t".'<input type="hidden" name="val1" value="'.$col_value.'" />"'`

Comment: @Dagon but he has used it in a loop, so when $i will be equal to 2 then $_POST['val2'] should be printed

Comment: This makes no sense ... Why don't you just output all 2 (6?) "cells" in one single row? Without any `for` and `if/elseif`??

Comment: Because they are not in the same row, they are in the same column.

Comment: Really? I see one opening `<tr>` and then ...

Comment: Right.  One row contains val1.  One row contains val2 and so on.  Each val is in a different row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just so that there is a detailed answer on here, I will answer my own question.

Here is an example of how I solved this.  This loop is done before the form:

```
    if($table == 'language'){                       //this cycles through query to get value of $language... but it only gets last value of language from search query
        $numRow = 0;
        //results are good so output them to HTML
        while ($line1 = pg_fetch_array($result, null, PGSQL_ASSOC)){
            $counter = 0;

            foreach ($line1 as $col_value){ // then add all data for attributes in succeeding columns
                if($counter == 1){
                    $language[$numRow] = $col_value;//array($numRow => $col_value);
                    $counter++;
                }
                else
                    $counter++;
            }
            $numRow++;
        }
```

And this is how the info is added in the form:

```
        echo "\t\t<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"language\" value=\"$language[$numRow]\" />";
```

Answer (score 0):

I maybe suggest splitting up into 2 forms to see what you want to accomplish.
What would you like to show in the output?
This code seems to be a SELF POST.
Also change the hidden text boxes to normal textbozes so that you can see what is happening to the code.

```
  <form action=""  method="post">
  <?php
  $counter = 1; //default values are always good to have
  $col_value = 0;
  $col_value = @$_POST['val1'] ;

  if ($counter == 1)
      echo "\t\t<input  name='val1'   value='$col_value' />";
  else 
      echo "\t\t<input  name='val2' value='$col_value' />";

  //I would rather write it like this:

  $line = 1;
  $counter = 1; //give it a default value to start off with.
  $col_value = @$_POST['val1'] ;
  $col_value = 0;

  $line = array(1, 2,4);
     foreach ($line as $col_value) {
     echo "Current value of \$line: $col_value.\n";
  echo "<input  name='val1' value='$col_value' />";
  echo "<input  name='val2' value='$col_value' />";
     }

  ?>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
  <br>
  <br>
  <table>
  <?php

  $val1 = $_POST['val1'] ;
  $val2 = $_POST['val2'] ;
  echo "POSTval1: ".$val1."<br>";
  echo "POSTval2: ".$val2."<br>";

  for($i=1; $i<6; $i++) {
      echo "\t<tr>\n";
      echo "\t\t<td>";

      if($i == 1){
          echo "id";
          echo "</td>\n";
          echo "\t\t<td>" . $val1 . "</td>\n";

      } elseif($i == 2){
          echo "name";
          echo "</td>\n";
          echo "\t\t<td>" . $val2 . "</td>\n";
      }
  } //don't forget the closing brackets.
  ?>

  </table>
  </form>
```